# Thymeleaf: resolve most specific of multiple message codes

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have an array of possible i18n message codes. Lets call it `codes`. Let's assume it contains values

```
[most.specific, specific, default]
```

Let's assume the messages.properties contains messages for `specific` and `default`, but not for `most.specific`.

I would be happy to be able to write in my Thymeleaf template something like

```
#{${codes}}
```

to get a message for `specific` code (since it is the first one that is defined).

I need Thymeleaf to resolve the first available message code that is defined in messages file into a string, ignoring the other message codes.

How to do this concisely?

Comment: I believe `LocaleResolver` ,`LocaleChangeInterceptor` will do that by default.

Comment: @soorapadman: my question has nothing to do with locale resolution. I have expanded the question to make it more explicit.